# Excerpt of certain page to display on home page

Tags: excerpt

I would like to ask something about Wordpress. For example: When i designing a web page, I want to have a column on **homepage** that displays an **excerpt** of the **About Page**(which is inner page). Is there any coding that makes this work? Any solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a new loop - outside of your main loop - using [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and passing the page `ID` for the 'About' page and setting `post_type` to `page` Then, inside your new loop simply call [`get_the_excerpt()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt)

Update:
From my links:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'page' );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <li>
        <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>

</ul>
```

Should do the trick. I just made minor edits to the examples in the provided links. It's explained better there than I can but it's best to understand the 'how' and 'why' of this; there are important, basic WP concepts in use.

Comment: How to do so? Because i don't really know about it. Any code you can show me?